# How to dynamically generate different fields based on previous selection of select field in Flask WTForm

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask, flask-wtforms

I would like to implement a form that generates different text area fields depending on what value was selected in the dropdown select field before hand. The context is creating projects of different categories: for example, if a user selects "Education", the next fields generated live could be a select field for "quarter/semester?", and a text area field for "Describe your subject matter". I understand that accomplishing such a feature requires javascript/jquery but I have no idea where to start. I am also unsure the best way to relate this to my models and database.

In my HTML template, I have implemented if statements but these of course don't work.

My form class looks something like this:

```py
class ProjectForm(FlaskForm):
    """Create a new project, on /index"""
    categories = ['Education','Software development', ...]
    langs = ['Python', 'Java', ...]
    name = TextAreaField('Give your project a name', validators=[
        DataRequired(), Length(min=1, max=60)])
    category = SelectField('Category', choices=categories, default=1)
    
    #Education case
    academic_pace = SelectField('Quarter or semester?', choices=['quarter', 'semester'], 
    default=1)
    subject = TextAreaField('Describe your subject matter', validators=[
        DataRequired(), Length(min=10, max=100)])
    
    #Software development case
    software_language = SelectField('What programming language??', choices=langs, default=1)
    
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

The route like this:

```py
from app.models import User, Project
from app.forms import LoginForm, ProjectForm ...
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def index():
    form = ProjectForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        project = Project(name = form.name.data, category = form.category.data, 
                          academic_pace = form.academic_pace.data, 
                          subject = form.subject.data, 
                          software_language = form.software_language.data, 
    creator=current_user)
        db.session.add(project)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your project is now live!')
        return redirect(url_for('index')) 
    
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', form = form)
```

index.html:

```html
...
{{ form.category.label }}<br>            
{{ form.category(cols=32, rows=4) }}<br>  
{% for error in form.category.errors %}
    <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
{% endfor %}

{% if form.category == "Education" %}
     {{ form.academic_pace.label }}<br>            
     {{ form.academic_pace(cols=32, rows=4) }}<br> 
     {% for error in form.academic_pace.errors %}
         <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
     {% endfor %}

     {{ form.subject.label }}<br>            
     {{ form.subject(cols=32, rows=4) }}<br> 
     {% for error in form.subject.errors %}
         <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
     {% endfor %}
 {% endif %}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out how to do this using jquery. Essentially for each category's unique forms, I wrap them in a div. These divs are hidden at first, with `style="display:none;"`. I use jquery to then identify what options are being selected from the SelectField, and show or hide the other form divs accordingly. Below is the javascript for one case.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#category").change(function () { 
        var val = $(this).val();
            if (val == "learning") {
                $("#learning").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#learning").hide(); 
            }
        });     
});
```